# Why am I getting status as 'subscribe'?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

User  named `tester` added another user `sanika` in his roster.The subscription mode for `sanika` is set to be ***`Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all`***. But when `tester` checks the status of `sanika` he gets `subscribe`. Why is it so ?

In the function main,`sanika` sets her status and in the function `connectTester` tester,tries to get the status of `sanika`.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
             Connection connection = new XMPPConnection("localhost");
             connection.connect();
             connection.login("sanika", "tester");

             Roster r = connection.getRoster();

             r.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);

             Presence p = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
             p.setStatus("Having Lunch :)");

             connection.sendPacket(p);

             connectTester();

             Thread.sleep(30000);

         }   catch(Exception exc) {
             exc.printStackTrace();
             }   
    }

    public static void connectTester() {
        try {
            Connection connection = new XMPPConnection("localhost");
            connection.connect();
            connection.login("tester", "tester");

            Roster r = connection.getRoster();
            RosterEntry re = r.getEntry("sanika@sanika.com");
            System.out.println(re.getStatus().toString()); 
            // PRINTS SUBSCRIBE

        }catch(Exception exc) {}
```

Where am I making a mistake ?

*Note :* `tester` added `sanika` as :

```
        String group[] = {"Friend List"};
        r.createGroup("Friend List");
        r.createEntry("sanika@sanika.com", "sanika", group);
```

Answer (score 0):

I add two users to each others roster as follow

```
//subscribe to eachother
connection.login("tester", ...); 
Presence subscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
subscribe.setTo("sanika@sanika.com");
connection.sendPacket(subscribe);
connection.disconnect();
...                
connection.connect();
connection.login("sanika", ...); 
subscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
subscribe.setTo("tester@localhost");
connection.sendPacket(subscribe);
connection.disconnect();
```

Note also that you seem to use both `sanika@sanika.com` and `sanika@localhost` (the first `login`-statement in `main`)

Comment: I have posted a query..If we could discuss it here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40703/discussion-between-suhail-and-marc-van-daele

Comment: I posted a query there